# Protect sql injections at the PHP level

Tags: php, sql, pdo, code-injection

I have some older code to maintain and I am worried about SQL injections, but I cannot use PDO. I would like instead to have a top level PHP function to examine $_GET and $_POST and stop the script if anything suspicious is found.

What would be a good function to write at this point?
For example, I could start with that:

```
$flag = 0;
$req = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);
foreach ($req as $rx)
{
    if (strpos(strtolower($rx), 'drop ') !== false)
        $flag = 1;
    if (htmlspecialchars($rx,ENT_QUOTES) !== $rx)
        $flag = 1;
....
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: In effect, you want to reinvent the `magic quotes` feature which has been removed from PHP long ago due to fatal inefficiency.

Comment: So if $rx contained the perfectly valid "I fancy a drop, want to join me in the pub?" you'd treat it as invalid?

Comment: You dnt want to use the mysql_real_escape_string() ?

Comment: @HassanALi JFYI, this function is not intended to protect from SQL injection and thus shouldn't be used for this purpose.

Comment: @MarkBaker yes, this is a greek registration database, only greek personal user information is allowed.